# Update apps PlayStore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What can i do ?

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAhEg.png)

I have change property set to other, but still..

Comment: Did you click the link in the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By just adding **exported:true** to your Android manifest activity did not solve my issue. Probably because the libraries your application depends on does not have **exported:true** You shouldn't encounter this bug in the future as long as the libraries are updated with **exported:true**

Video demo here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hy0J8MNnE6g

Comment: Oke Mr.Dipak.. Tq so much.
Lemme try